# best practices for demo-site replication of a membership bug?

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, contribution-page

I think I've encountered a veeeeeery use-case-specific bug with online user-driven  membership renewals and I'm trying to replicate it on the demo server to confirm. We're on drupal 7 and the issue pertains to users renewing their own on-behalf memberships as logged-in CMS users. The demo site is (rightly) nerfed from sending emails, so new drupal users never get their activation emails, so I can't find a way to fully create a new CMS user and log in as them to test. What's the best practice for doing this?

Comment: what prevents you testing using the demo/demo user?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion I feel like I need to test with a user that does not have "administer CiviCRM" permission in drupal, as that's the use-case where I'm encountering the error. Sure I can renew someone as a CiviCRM admin, but the problem occurs when regular CMS users try to self-renew.

Answer (score 1):

As you are in Drupal, i recommend using the drupal module [masquerade](https://www.drupal.org/project/masquerade) which let you act as if logged in as another user.

Otherwise, with drush you could generate a one-time login for the user you want without sending an email. So from the command line, type : `drush uli user-name` and you will get a link that will log-in as the user `user-name`

Comment: Just to clarify, I am trying to replicate the bug on the demo server (demo.civicrm.org) which I don't assume I can drush into - or can i?

Comment: oh, ok, i don't think you can do this. I recommend you create a clone of your production site or otherwise create your own demo site by installing a brand new civicrm with sample data in it.